# Matlab: Search everywhere shortcut

Tags: matlab, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

Is there any shortcut in Matlab comparable to `Search Everywhere` in the JetBrains universe or `Control-P` in Sublime?

A shortcut that searches for files/ folder/ functions etc. in the current directory and makes it possible to switch there by pressing `enter`?

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `F` brings up the 'find in files' dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: [Find Files and Folders](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/finding-files-and-folders.html). And you probably want to use the advanced features:

> To conduct an advanced search for files, you can use the Find Files
>   tool. Use the Find Files tool to:
>
> - Search for specific text in file names and within files
> - Include or exclude specified file types from your search
> - Search in specified folders
> - Exclude large files from your search
>
> To open the Find Files tool, on the Home tab, in the File section,
>   click Find Files. Enter your search criteria in the dialog box that
>   opens.

The keyboard shortcut shoud be `CTRL+SHIFT+F` but I'm not sure.

[image: Screen]

Comment: Close to what I want but a little laborious in my opinion :/